# Specifing a Sharded Collection with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data MongoDB to interface with an underlying sharded MongoDB cluster. My Spring Boot Application access the cluster via a `mongos` router.

Using Spring Data MongoDB, you can specify the collection an object is persisted to via `@Document(collection = "nameOfCollection")`, or it defaults to the class name (first letter lowercase). These collections do not need to exist before-hand; they can be created at runtime.

To shard a collection in MongoDB, you need to

1 - Enable sharding on the Database: `sh.enableSharding("myDb")`

2 - Shard the collection on a sharded database: `sh.shardCollection("myDb.myCollection", {id:"hashed"})`

Assuming there is an existing sharded database, **does Spring Data MongoDB offer a way to shard a collection with a shard key?** As far as I can tell, I cannot shard a collection with Spring, and therefore must configure the sharded collection before my Boot application runs. I find it odd that Spring would allow me to use undefined collections, but does not provide a way to configure the collection.

**Edit:**
I have seen both [Sharding with spring mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497070/sharding-with-spring-mongo) and [How configuring access to a sharded collection in spring-data for mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647829/how-configuring-access-to-a-sharded-collection-in-spring-data-for-mongo) which refer more to the deployment of a sharded MongoDB cluster. This question assumes all the plumbing is there and that the collection itself simply must be sharded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite this question being old, I've got the same question, and it looks like there is away to provide custom sharding key since recently.

Annotation-based Shard Key configuration is available on `spring-data-mongodb:3.x`, 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/#sharding

```java
@Document("users")
@Sharded(shardKey = { "country", "userId" }) 
public class User {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Field("userid")
    String userId;

    String country;
}
```

As of today `spring-boot-starter-mongodb` comes with 2.x version though.

Comment: This is available in spring-data-mongodb 3.0 as per the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#new-features.3.0. However, i could not find the maven dependency. Is spring-data-mongodb 3.0 available for use?

Comment: You can use it with spring-boot version 2.3.0.M3 which can be pulled from snapshot repositories. Installation guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-installing-spring-boot

Answer (score 2):

Was running into the same problem with our update queries that internally used a save().

How it was solved?

So I now have overridden the spring-data-mongo core dependency from spring-boot-starter which is 2.1.x by 3.x release in our model which is now supporting @Sharded() annotation .

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

allows you to say

```
@Document(collection = "hotelsdevice")
@Sharded(shardKey = { "device" })

public class Hotel extends BaseModel {
```

which internally is now able to tell the underlying mongo which is our shardkey. I am assuming this will further fix our count() queries too which were failing due to the same error "query need to target a shard "

Comment: This is the solution, notice if Document or Sharded annotation values do not match your Azure resource, CosmosDB will fail with confusing error "query in command must target a single shard key"

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not a Spring Data solution, a potential workaround is posed in [how to execute mongo admin command from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394917/how-to-execute-mongo-admin-command-from-java), where `DB` can be acquired from a Spring `MongoTemplate`.

```
DB db = mongo.getDB("admin");
DBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject();
cmd.put("shardcollection", "testDB.x");
cmd.put("key", new BasicDBObject("userId", 1));
CommandResult result = db.command(cmd);
```